# How to calculate age in POSTGRES for multiple columns and conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that records weather readings for many locations & I need a summary for each location that shows days since an extreme weather event

```
CREATE TABLE appl.weather_readings (
   location_id INT,
   rec_date DATE DEFAULT NOW(),
   temp NUMERIC,
   wind_gust NUMERIC,
   rain NUMERIC,
   uv NUMERIC,
   hail NUMERIC
)
```

Example data is

```
|location_id | rec_date  | temp | wind_gust | rain | uv | hail|
|----------- | --------  | -----| ----------| -----| -- | ----|
|1           |2021-06-01 | 45.0 | 5.0       |  0.0 |21.0|  0  |
|2           |2021-06-01 | 30.0 | 15.0      |  0.0 |20.0|  0  |
|1           |2021-06-02 | 37.0 | 7.0       |  0.0 |20.0|  0  |
```

I need a query that shows the days since an extreme weather event for each location. An extreme event might be defined as temp > 43 OR wind_gust OR rain > 50
I can get the age of a single condition only

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (location_id) location_id, rec_date, temp, wind_gust, uv, hail,
AGE(rec_date) as days_since_extreme_temp
   FROM appl.weather_readings
   WHERE temp > 43
  ORDER BY location_id, rec_date DESC;
```

But how can I get an age of each condition in 1 query. I need a return value that looks like this with 1 row for each location ID

```
|location_id | days_since_extreme_temp  | days_since_extreme_rain | days_since_extreme_uv | etc |
|----------- | --------                 | -----                   | ----------            | ----|
|1           |41                        | 105                     | 58                    |  103|
|2           |103                       | 76                      | 12                    |  129|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
select location_id, 
   age(max(rec_date) filter (where temp > 43)) days_since_extreme_temp, 
   age(max(rec_date) filter (where rain > 50)) days_since_extreme_rain
from weather_readings
group by location_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lateral join`:

```sql
select t.location_id, 
   age(lat.max_extreme_temp_date) days_since_extreme_temp, 
   age(lat.max_extreme_rain_date) days_since_extreme_rain,
   ... etc
from (select distinct location_id from weather_readings) t 
cross join lateral 
( 
 select 
    max(rec_date) filter (where  temp > 43) max_extreme_temp_date,
    max(rec_date) filter (where  rain > 50) max_extreme_rain_date
    ... etc
 from weather_readings wr 
 where wr.location_id = t.location_id
) lat;
```